# QT Powrprof.h functions not declared in scope

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, mingw

I'm trying to use the powrprof.h functions in QT, specifically the PowerGetActiveScheme function, and am having some trouble.
I've started a fresh project, and this is my main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "winbase.h"
#include "powrprof.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    GUID* gp = new GUID;
    GUID** gpp = &gp;
    PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL,gpp);
    return a.exec();
}
```

When I try to build/run this, QT gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Qt\DebugTest\main.cpp:18: error: 'PowerGetActiveScheme' was not declared in this scope
 PowerGetActiveScheme(gpp);
                         ^
```

I was able to get this work fine in Visual Studio by replacing `#include "powrprof.h` with

```
extern "C" {

#include <PowrProf.h>
}
#pragma comment(lib, "powrprof.lib")
```

But this doesn't work in QT, and it tells me that it is ignoring the #pragma comment.

So far I have tried:

Replacing the Powrprof.h file in C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\ with the one from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\
Which then gave me the error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powrprof.h:18: error: powerbase.h: No such file or directory
```

So then I copied powerbase.h from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\ to C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\

Which then gave me this error: `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powrprof.h:19: error: powersetting.h: No such file or directory`

So once again, I copied powersetting.h to the directory.

Which then leaves me where I am at now, with all of these errors:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powerbase.h:71: error: '_Out_writes_bytes_opt_' has not been declared
 _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(OutputBufferLength) PVOID OutputBuffer,
 ^

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powerbase.h:71: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'PVOID'
 _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(OutputBufferLength) PVOID OutputBuffer,
                                            ^

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powrprof.h:1025: error: '_Out_writes_bytes_opt_' has not been declared
 _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(*pBufferSize) PBYTE  pReturnBuffer,
 ^

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\powrprof.h:1025: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'PBYTE'
 _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(*pBufferSize) PBYTE  pReturnBuffer,
                                      ^
```

And of course,

```
C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Qt\DebugTest\main.cpp:14: error: 'PowerGetActiveScheme' was not declared in this scope
 PowerGetActiveScheme(gpp);
                         ^
```

I have also tried putting the relevant headers in the local project folder, attempting to use LIBS += in the .pro file to include the .libs, as was suggested in some answers, using the add existing files function to add both the .h and .lib files, and probably some other stuff I have forgotten.

Here is my .pro file(Fresh project, previous debugging attempts in it not shown):

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-06-13T12:51:15
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DebugTest
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

If its important, what I was originally trying to do was to create a program that would auto switch power plans on a laptop depending on if it was plugged in or on battery.

Comment: If you look at the documentaion for the PowerGetActiveScheme() function you will see that you are missing a parameter. It should be PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, gpp). Also if you are building with msvc your pragma comment should work fine.

Comment: Ah right, forgot that part. Same errors though. Right now I'm building with MinGW, but I'm about to attempt to build with MSVC(Downloading stuff right now).

Comment: Vanilla MinGW is outdated. If you want to stay with it, use MinGW-w64 instead.

Comment: Hmm according to the documentation you shouldn't be including WinBase.h directly as it expects some things to be defined before being processed. Including Windows.h and powrprof.h in your case should be sufficient.

Comment: I eventually fixed it by uninstalling Qt and the 2017 version of Visual C++ and Visual Studio, and installing the MSVC version of QT and the 2015 version of Visual C++ and VS. It worked after that, as the #pragma comments weren't ignored like they were in MinGW. @aatwo I must have added that somewhere along the line when trying everything I could think of to fix it, thanks for catching that. 

Thanks to both of you for your help, I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now and am glad to have resolved it.